# DVD stops working in windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, optical-drive, 64-bit

I have the same problem as described in this question:
[DVD/CD-ROM drives stop working in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/105928/dvd-cd-rom-drives-stop-working-in-windows-7)
I know I have got some games that are using starforce and/or securerom. What I don't have is the upper and lower filter in my registry tag. Oh and a reboot temporarily fixes my problem. After a random time though it goes missing again.

I found a Microsoft knowledge base article regarding this but since I didn't have the filter tags they couldn't help me. Does anyone have any other tips bar removing the despicable drm:s? I would like to go on playing my games so that is not really an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying another dvd drive, just to rule out hardware problems.

Also, check for a firmware update for your current dvd drive.

Answer (score 0):

Since how long you are facing issue with your computer. Is your computer dvd drive recognise any disc or not. IF not then try to boot your computer from Windows 7 Dvd and check are you getting any message "Press any key to boot from cd or dvd " or not. Check in device manager if getting any yellow mark in front of dvd drive. Perform system restore on your computer first.